# VBS Runs from Explorer but not Task Scheduler

Tags: vbscript

I have a legacy VBS script that runs on a schedule via task scheduler. The script checks a folder (located in a mapped network drive) and processes the files it finds in the folder.

Recently it just stopped working. I didn't write this script, I've only inherited it. It no longer seems to find files in the folder it's looking in, even when they're there. To test we created a log file and wrote file names to it. When manually double-clicking the file and running it from explorer it writes to the log file and sees everything in the directory. If you run it from the Task Scheduler it sees no files and writes nothing to the log file. It also runs for days and never seems to exit when the scheduler runs it, even if there are no files and when I run manually it closes immediately when there are no files.

We have several other legacy scripts that are very similar in function to this one and they all work exactly as expected without issue.

This script is run as administrator (the others are as well). I set the "Start In" to it's current directory (the start in directive is not set for the other scripts and they function normally) and this did not help.

This script uses full file paths to everything (the others do as well).

It works as expected only when double clicked.

Comment: Its unlikely to have access to mapped drives. Drives are mapped per user token, admins have two user tokens - one when Run As Admin and one when not. There is no need for mapped drives in Windows (a 20+ year old DOS compatibility thing), use UNC `\\servername\sharename\folder\file.ext`.

Comment: @Noodles I didn't write this script, and I'm not opposed to modifying it, but there are several other scripts that are run exactly the same way accessing the same mapped drive and working without issue which is what makes this weird.

Comment: If you map a drive when not elevated the mapping doesn't exist when you Run As Admin. So the change occurred in your system - look at how you map drives.

Comment: But all the scripts are ran as admin which is why this is so confounding. I've gone over all the scheduler settings and they're the same for every task, including this one that's being problematic and they all access the network share drive P:\

Comment: Look at how the drive is being mapped for that specific user. Post your code anyway. Also specify what user are you using (an inbuilt account?).

Comment: Aside from the fact that this is a question for SuperUser, how do you expect anyone who isn't sitting in front of your computer to troubleshoot this with no information about your code, almost no information about the task configuration, and no logs?

Comment: Running as admin might not be the only problem, there is also a setting "run with highest privileges". Is this by chance only true for this script?

Comment: I'll add some more info.